# How do I center my canvas without it effecting the drawing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my canvas more responsive, by first making it centered on the screen and then making it resize with the browser to a min & max height so for instance, it should only get to 800x800 if the browser is full width and height and then like 400x400 at minimum if I resize it down to a smaller resolution.

I've tried adding this in the css

```
position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:auto;
```

But that only made it so that I couldn't draw and I am quite confused to why that is.
Would I have to use the min-width and height properties in order to make it more responsive or do I have to use that one thing in the css where you use the @ character?
I can't quite recall the technical term for what it's called but I know I've used it before when working with other small projects like this.
I am still quite new to web developments.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    canvas.width = 400;
    canvas.height = 400;
    //Resizing


    //Variables
    let painting = false;

    function startPosition(e) {
        painting = true;
        paint(e);
    }
    
    function endPosition(){
        painting = false;
        ctx.beginPath();
    }
    
    function paint(e){
        //If mousebutton is not pressed.
        if(!painting) return;

        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'orange';
        ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    }

    
    //EventListeners
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', endPosition);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', paint);



});


//  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
//     canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
//     canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
//  });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./resources/style.css">
    <title>Artsy</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="./resources/canvas.js"></script>

</html>
```

I realized that you need to change the canvas width and height using the correct properties either in the javascript file which I did or inline in the html element inside the html file and not changing the element itself because the canvas is made up out of two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `text-align` css property of the parent element of the canvas to `center`, the canvas should get centered, and if you want it to get a width according to the size of the device you should use `width` css property to `100%` in the canvas or use JavaScript `screen.width` && `screen.height` properties.

Comment: If I do that, then it wont let me draw